# Disable input language switching shortcut

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, language, input-languages

I'm not sure what the issue is on my Windows computer but I can't seem to determine what triggers the input language switcher that I seem to accidentally press too often.

I have three inputs set up:

1. English - US Keyboard
2. French - US Keyboard
3. French - Canadian Multilingual Standard Keyboard

I know that <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> triggers a menu to choose a language but I know that is **not** what I accidentally hit because 1) the menu doesn't show up and 2) it is rare to press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> accidentally.

I've heard that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> is also another combination and it seems plausible that that's triggering the behaviour but it isn't because I just tried to replicate the problem and have tried all combinations of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

The thing is, my input preferences have no keyboard shortcuts configured:
[image: Screenshot of input preferences window]

How do I disable it?